# Stub out module function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

Edit: Being a little bit more precise.

I want to test usecases for a Github API wrapper extension, that our team has created. For testing, we don't want to use API wrapper extension directly, so we want to stub out its functions. All calls to the API wrapper should be stubbed out for the tests, not just creating a clone stub.

I have a module "github" in Node.js:

```
module.exports = function(args, done) {
    ...
}
```

And I am requiring it like this:

```
var github = require('../services/github');
```

Now, I would like to stub out `github(...)` using Sinon.js:

```
var stub_github = sinon.stub(???, "github", function (args, callback) { 
    console.log("the github(...) call was stubbed out!!");
});
```

But `sinon.stub(...)` expects from me to pass an object and a method and does not allow me to stub out a module that is a function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There might be a way to accomplish this in pure Sinon, but I suspect it would be pretty hacky.  However, [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) is a node library that is designed for solving these sort of issues.

Supposing you want to test some module `foo` that makes use of the github module; you'd write something like:

```
var proxyquire = require("proxyquire");
var foo = proxyquire(".foo", {"./github", myFakeGithubStub});
```

where `myFakeGithubStub` can be anything; a complete stub, or the actual implementation with a few tweaks, etc.

If, in the above example, `myFakeGithubStub` has a property "@global" set as true, (i.e. by executing `myFakeGithubStub["@global"] = true`) then the github module will be replaced with the stub not only in the `foo` module itself, but in any module that the `foo` module requires.  However, as stated in the [proxyquire documentation on the global option](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire#globally-override-require), generally speaking this feature is a sign of poorly designed unit tests and should be avoided.

Comment: Okay, I was a little bit unclear. I don't want to just stub out the module in the test scope, I want to stub it out for every module that I use in the test. Your solution works, if I call github(...) directly within the test, but all other modules still use the original implementation.

Comment: Proxyquire can do this; though they recommend against it in their documentation, saying it's often a sign of poor unit test design.  See here: https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire#globally-override-require .  I'll update my answer to mention this.

Answer (score 9):

I found that this worked for me...

```
const sinon          = require( 'sinon' );
const moduleFunction = require( 'moduleFunction' );

//    Required modules get added require.cache. 
//    The property name of the object containing the module in require.cache is 
//    the fully qualified path of the module e.g. '/Users/Bill/project/node_modules/moduleFunction/index.js'
//    You can get the fully qualified path of a module from require.resolve
//    The reference to the module itself is the exports property

const stubbedModule = sinon.stub( require.cache[ require.resolve( 'moduleFunction' ) ], 'exports', () => {

    //    this function will replace the module

    return 'I\'m stubbed!';
});

// sidenote - stubbedModule.default references the original module...
```

You have to make sure that you stub the module (as above) before it's required elsewhere...

```
// elsewhere...

const moduleFunction = require( 'moduleFunction' ); 

moduleFunction();    // returns 'I'm stubbed!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is to refactor your module:

instead of this:

```
module.exports = function(args, done) {
    ...
}
```

do this:

```
module.exports = function(){
    return module.exports.github.apply(this, arguments);
};
module.exports.github = github;

function github(args, done) {
    ...
}
```

Now you can require it with:

```
const github = require('../services/github.js');
//or
const github = require('../services/github.js').github;
```

To stub:

```
const github = require('../services/github.js');
let githubStub = sinon.stub(github, 'github', function () {
    ... 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are doing

`var github = require('../services/github');`

in global scope, then you can using 'global' as the object and 'github' as the method to be stubbed out.

```
var stub_github = sinon.stub(global, "github", function (args, callback) { 
    console.log("the github(...) call was stubbed out!!");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work: ```TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property github as function```

Comment: Where are you executing sinon.stub(..)? It is also supposed to be in the global scope.
Or you can try 
`var stub_github = sinon.stub(global, "github", function (args, callback) { 
    console.log("the github(...) call was stubbed out!!");
});`

Comment: Doesn't work either. sinon.stub(...) is called in a testcase, "github" is defined in the same scope.